# Enquiries regarding securing strong password and ssh

Tags: ipv4, rip

I am a beginner in computer network and I have done some research with regards on how to do IP configuration on PC and routers. However, I am not sure on how to configure strong password and ssh based on the following network topology shown, as I have researched online and tried out various exercises on configuring strong passwords for different network topology. All I understand so far, is that the switch and router need to be configured with ssh and strong password. But in the following topology, since I have configured the router with strong password and ssh, do I have to configure the switch too? Please enlighten me on this

Thank you[image: topology]

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to use ssh and to configure strong passwords on any device that you remotely manage.  That includes routers, switches, firewalls, *etc.*

Comment: I'm sorry, but i dont know what you mean by remotely manage

Comment: I mean, if you can use telnet, ssh, http, *etc* to manage the device

Comment: So basically, if I want to configure secure password and ssh on both routers and switches, it's fine right?

Comment: The reason you configure passwords, *etc.* on devices is to prevent someone else from changing the configuration.  if that is important to you (and it should be), then configure it.  If not, then don't bother.